# neutral label for NLTK

Tags: nltk, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, multilabel-classification, nltk-trainer

I have similar problem like below

[Why did NLTK NaiveBayes classifier misclassify one record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335460/why-did-nltk-naivebayes-classifier-misclassify-one-record)

In my case, I queried positive feed and built positive_vocab and then queried negative feed and built negative_voca. I get the data from feed clean and built the classifier. How do I build the neutral_vocab. Is there a way I can instruct NLTK classifier to return neutral label when the given word is not found in the negative_voca and positive_vocab. How do I do that?

In my current implementation, if I give a word which is not present in the both sets it tells positive by default. Instead it should tell, neutral or notfound

Comment: You need to train a three-way classifier with a three-way training set.

Comment: I have data for positive and negative vocabulary I can get them from a feed. I don't have a feed for neutral vocabulary. So, if the given input doesn't match positive or negative then it should return as neutral. How can I do this?

Comment: I heard you. You need to train a three-way classifier with a three-way training set.